# Multiple leftJoins using Laravel's Query Builder producing incorrect counts

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4's Query Builder to perform a series of leftJoins on three tables. Here are my tables:

**items**

```
id  type  title                visibility  status  created_at  
--  ----  -----                ----------  ------  ----------
1   1     This is a Title      1           1       2017-06-20 06:39:20
2   1     Here's Another Item  1           1       2017-06-24 18:12:13
3   1     A Third Item         1           1       2017-06-26 10:10:34
```

**count_loves**

```
id  items_id  user_id
--  -------   -------
1   1         2
2   1         57
3   1         18
```

**count_downloads**

```
id  items_id  user_id
--  -------   -------
1   1         879
2   1         323
```

And here is the code I am running in Laravel:

```
    $items_output = DB::table('items')
        ->leftJoin('count_loves', 'items.id', '=', 'count_loves.items_id')
        ->leftJoin('count_downloads', 'items.id', '=', 'count_downloads.items_id')
        ->where('items.visibility', '=', '1')
        ->where('items.status', '=', '1')
        ->orderBy('items.created_at', 'desc')
        ->select('items.*', DB::raw('count(count_loves.id) as loveCount'), DB::raw('count(count_downloads.id) as downloadCount'))
        ->groupBy('items.id')
        ->get();
```

When I return the results for this query, I am getting the following counts:

**count_loves**: 6

**count_downloads**: 6

As you can see, the actual count values should be:

**count_loves**: 3

**count_downloads**: 2

If I add another entry to the *count_loves* table, as an example, the totals move to 8. If I add another entry to the *count_downloads* table after that, the totals jump to 12. So, the two counts are multiplying together.

If I die and dump the query, here's what I get:

> "query" => "select 'items'.*, count(count_loves.id) as loveCount,
>   count(count_downloads.id) as downloadCount from 'items' left join
>   'count_loves' on 'items'.'id' = 'count_loves'.'items_id' left join
>   'count_downloads' on 'items'.'id' = 'count_downloads'.'items_id'
>   where 'items'.'visibility' = ? and 'items'.'status' = ? group by
>   'items'.'id' order by 'items'.'created_at' desc"

How do I perform multiple leftJoins using Query Builder and *count* on several tables to return the proper sums?

Comment: what about using    

->andwhere('items.status', '=', '1')  instead of twice where which would cancel the first one.

Comment: @Arminius - is there documentation for ``andwhere`` in Laravel 5.4? If I replace with it, it fails in the query builder.

Comment: I beg you pardon, that is in Symfony. And using 'and' instead?

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:

This is intended as a HELP answer not the total absolute answer but I could not write the code in a comment. I am not asking for votes (for those who just can't wait to downvote me). I have created your tables and tried a UNION query on raw sql. I got correct results. I dont have laravel installed, but maybe you could try a UNION query in Laravel.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#unions

```
select count(count_downloads.user_id) 
from count_downloads
join items
on items.id = count_downloads.items_id
UNION 
select count(count_loves.user_id)
from count_loves
join items
on items.id = count_loves.items_id
```